# Как перебрать ассоциативный массив и перезаписать в нем данные?

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер.

Есть ассоциативный массив с функцией добавления в него:

```
var usersData = []; 
var usersObj = {id: i, name: '', email: ''};`

function AddUser(name, email, id) {
    usersData.push({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        id: i++
    });
}
```

Как через консоль в этом массиве перезаписать данные одного из элементов, если я захочу например изменить email или имя.

Comment: javascript - регистрозависимый язык. UsersData и usersData - 2 разные переменные

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по коду с вопроса, функция AddUser будет добавлять в масив usersData  обычный обьект и доступ к его свойствам будет осуществляться через индекс конкретного обьекта в масиве + название свойства, и изменить то же имя с консоли можно будет так :

```
usersData[0]['name'] = 'new user name at element 0';
```

или так :

```
usersData[0].name = 'new user name at element 0';
```

если надо изменить имя во всех обьектах-елементах масива :

```
function editAll(paramName, paramValue){
    for (var j = 0; j < usersData.length; j++) {
        usersData[j][paramName] = paramValue;
    };
};
```

Не сразу заметил что редактировать нужно не все, а *нужный* елемент, для етого надо придумать условие по которому будет определяться *нужный* елемент, например редактирование елементов с четным **id** :

```js
"use strict";

var i = 0;
var usersData = [];

for (var k = 0 ; k < 10; k++){
  AddUser('name ' + k , 'email ' + k);
};

var oldArray = usersData;

console.log(oldArray);

editAll('name' , 'new name', function(val){
  if(val == 0) return false;
  return !(val % 2);
});

console.log(usersData);

function AddUser(name, email) {
  usersData.push({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      id: i++
  });
};

function editAll(paramName, paramValue, f){
  for (var j = 0; j < usersData.length ; j++) {
      if(f(usersData[j].id)) {
          usersData[j][paramName] = paramValue;
      };
  };
};
```

в етом примере как определитель елемента, который нужно отредактировать я использовал функцию, но также можно прямо в editAll вставить условие с проверкой того ж id.

Comment: а если у меня например 50 таких элементов, как их перебрать и отредактировать нужный мне элемент?

Comment: добавил в ответ функцию, которая делает то что надо, но судя по всему тебе стоит почитать о масивах, обьектах, и о работе с ними